# passing multiple arrays to c3 graph

Tags: javascript, c3

I have an api giving me back multiple arrays I have to place on a c3 line chart. I seem to be able to plot on just fine, but if I start to pass in multiples it starts having a fit. I've done some searching, but from what I've seen mine needs to be more dynamic than calling out specific variable names in the data because I don't know how many I will have at any given time.

My code kind of looks like this

```
array1 = [];
array2 = [];
array 3 = [];
Data = ?;
 c3.generate({
 bindto: '.timeline',
                    data:{
                        columns: [
                            Data,
                        ],
                        axes: {
                            data2: 'x' // ADD
                        }
                    },
                    axis: {
                        y: {
                            label: { // ADD
                                text: 'Waiting',
                                position: 'outer-middle'
                            }
                        },
                        x: {
                            type: 'category',
                            categories: hour,
                            show: true, // ADD
                            label: { // ADD
                                text: '',
                                position: 'outer-center'
                            }   
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I've seen around to do something like this

```
columns: [
          Data1,
          Data2,
          Data3
],
```

Is there any way I can put those arrays into one variable to pass into the c3 graph? **I've tried making an array of arrays and passing that in. I've also tried putting them into an object, but that just blew it up too.** Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you make an array of arrays, it should work as shown in the functioning example in the answer I gave below. Unless you post the actual data for array1, array2 and array3, I can't tell if they have the correct data to make the graph work. (Your code also has `array 3` instead of `array3` as the variable name, so I assume this isn't 100% the actual code you're running). Can you either post your code/array data, or let me know where the answer I've given isn't working for you?

Answer (score 2):

Should be pretty straight-forward to get the three arrays into an array of arrays, which is the `columns` array.

```js
var array1 = ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250];
var array2 = ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25];
var array3 = ['data3', 230, 190, 300, 500, 300, 400];
var Data = [array1, array2, array3];

c3.generate({
  bindto: '.timeline',
  data: {
    columns: Data
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class='timeline' />
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! My code was actually working, but I couldn't see it because they all shared the same category and all the values were at 0 so it looked like only the first line was being drawn.